# Distinct DNS zone for active directory (samba4)

Tags: domain-name-system, samba, dnsmasq

I'm planning to use Samba4 as an AD domain controller in our local network to manage our ~30 Windows clients. But i still don't know how to integrate our current DHCP/DNS server(dnsmasq). I know that Samba needs its own DNS to work properly which would be either the integrated one or a BIND installation managed by a module.

I don't want to lose the ability to resolve something like `hostname.corp.mytld.com` to the IPv4/6 addresses of a machine. As far as i understand the DNS provided by Samba would only answer for clients which are part of the domain. This would exclude all our other devices if they're not a member of the domain e.g mobile devices and VMs.

Would it be possible to use something like `ad.mytld.com` as the DNS zone managed by Samba and let dnsmasq handle `corp.mytld.com` with latter being dynamically updated through DHCP? All entries would still point at the same IP subnet though.

In this scenario dnsmasq would be the primary DNS server propagated by DHCP and router advertisement which would delegate all queries for the AD zone to Samba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue by not using the DNS server provided by Samba. I ended up setting static SRV,A and CNAME entries in the dnsmasq config according to the following articels:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servergeeks/2014/07/12/dns-records-that-are-required-for-proper-functionality-of-active-directory/
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759550(v=ws.10).aspx